# Virtual host showing contents of file instead of serving the app

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, laravel-8

I have a `Laravel` application for which I am trying to create a `virtual host`. Here is the `.conf` file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName todo-app.test
    ServerAlias www.todo-app.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vuejs/todo-laravel/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/vuejs/todo-laravel">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine On
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       titan
127.0.0.1       todo-app.test
```

When I access the app in browser I get the contents of the `index.php` file instead of app getting launched. What is going wrong here?

I am on `Laravel` `8.40` with `Ubuntu 18.04`.

EDIT:
When I do `php artisan serve`, it works on this address, todo-app.test:8000 but I dont want port here. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Does any PHP work with the Apache server? Generally when this happens it’s because the PHP module hasn’t been installed.

Try this:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
```

You will need to restart Apache after the installation to ensure the module is properly applied:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I would suggest digging through your logs, then. My psychic powers are pretty much non-existent, which makes it difficult for me to manage your server from here.